# Setting DEBUG_STRICT_USER_COPY_CHECKS in extrenal kernel module

Tags: debugging, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm using very simple Makefile for my extrenal module and I've no idea how to set DEBUG_STRICT_USER_COPY_CHECKS. The only way I can make appear desired warning is by setting `KBUILD_CFLAGS := -DCONFIG_DEBUG_STRICT_USER_COPY_CHECKS=y`  but then I loose all other flags.

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)  clean
```

Thanks for any help, it's my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: `CONFIG_*` definitions are set during *configuration* of the kernel, because they affect *entire* kernel. You cannot set these definitions only for external module (that is, you can try to set them, but this probably will not work as you want).

Comment: Hmm thanks @Tsyvarev, so it seems there is no way to enable checking _user copy overflow_ in external module, right?

Comment: As I understand from [code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L655), `DEBUG_STRICT_USER_COPY_CHECKS` config options affects only on a way, how failed check would affect on compilation process: *error* or *warning*. Compile time check is performed in any case. You can achive *error* behaviour just adding `-Werror` to compilation flags. (For adding compile definitions see documentation under `Documentation/kbuild` in linux sources.)